# TextSelect in Pressable, how to give Pressable a higher priority in React Native?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

### Problem

I am trying to support selectable text on *iOS* and as the prop `selectable` does not work there, I had to resort to a `TextSelect`:

```
if (Platform.OS == “ios”) {
  return <TextInput style={textStyle} value={children} editable={false} multiline />;
}
```

I have some text in a Card component. This is basically text wrapped by a `Pressable`. My Problem is that I can't click most of the Card now, as only the `TextInput` seems to get triggered.

Is there a way to give the `Pressable` a higher priority? Something like `stopPropagation` in the web?

Comment: did you find the solution for this issue ?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. It is on the backburner for now. I will update the thread if I find a solution.